# Allow connections to only a specific URL via HTTPS with iptables, -m recent (potentially) and -m string (definitely)

Tags: https, nginx, wireshark, string-matching, iptables

Let's say that, for example, I want to allow connections *only* to subdomain.mydomain.com; I have it partially working, but it sometimes gets in a freaky loop with the client key exchange once the Client Hello is allowed.  Ah, to make it even more annoying, it's a self-signed certificate, and the page requires authentication, and HTTPS is listening on a non-standard port...  So the TCP/SSL Handshake experience will differ greatly for many users.

Is -m recent the right route?  Is there a more graceful method to allow the complete TCP stream once the string is seen?

Here's what I have so far:

```
#iptables -N SSL
#iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -j SSL
#iptables -A SSL -m recent --set -p tcp --syn --dport 400
#iptables -A SSL -m recent --update -p tcp --tcp-flags PSH,SYN,ACK SYN,ACK --sport 400
#iptables -A SSL -m recent --update -p tcp --tcp-flags PSH,SYN,ACK ACK --dport 400
#iptables -A SSL -m recent --remove -p tcp --tcp-flags PSH,ACK PSH,ACK --dport 400 -m string --algo kmp --string "subdomain.mydomain.com" -j ACCEPT
```

Yes, I have tried to get around this with nginx tweaks, but I can't get nginx to return a 444 before the client hello, if you can think of a way to achieve this instead, I'm all ears, err, eyes.

Comment: Belongs to http://serverfault.com

Comment: Thanks, I'll try posting it there too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned on [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/219963/allow-connections-to-only-a-specific-url-via-https-with-iptables-m-recent-pote), I have found a solution:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --tcp-flags FIN,PSH,ACK PSH,ACK --dport 400 -m connbytes --connbytes 0:512 --connbytes-dir original --connbytes-mode bytes -m string --algo bm ! --string "subdomain.mydomain.com" -j REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 400 -j ACCEPT
```